# Safe and secure way to keep encrypted data and private key in C# Dll

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, app-config, rsa

The question about storing connection string in safest way.

My current approach (Don't laugh)
1. Wrote RSAEncryption program and passed connection string to generate cypher.
2. Stored Cypher and private key in Resource file
3. Runtime retrieved encryption file again.

My concern of using config file
- I am creating library so projects who will use my dll will need to copy my config file which I dont want

Please tell me best practice to store connection string inside the dll.

Regards,
Omkar

Comment: Everything done programmatically can be reproduced manually

Comment: using config file? Can you please give me example?

Comment: You can retrieve the connection string regardless of how complex your local protection is, when the application connects to the database using a MITM attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built in mechanism in .NET to encrypt sections of config. The beauty is you can use DPAPI and have the machine itself create the key, so nobody knows what it is except Windows. The best thing is you get this pretty much for free (small learning curve) and the learning curve is easily handled with a quick Google search on encrypting configuration files. May not fit all scenarios, but it is more likely to be secure than a quickly envisioned alternative.

The only issue here is if this is shrinkwrap ware (ie, you are selling software), but there are ways to handle that by having the install require network and adding the bits they can't know while you encrypt only go into memory during install. :-)

Comment: The protection cost shouldn't be more that the product cost ;-)

Comment: hmmm. Really lot of overhead. Let me study it thoroughly before I come to the conclusion. Thanks a lot. If somebody wants to check information about it visit this link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx

Comment: the other disadvantage of this method is that it just works on the local computer - if you start the program from a shared directory this won't work. In the back of my head there is something for servers, but after that I didn't bother with it any more.